# Number doesn't increased by nothing after for loop

Tags: python, selenium

I created a program that enters Nytimes and search School Shooting and then I tried to search how many times the program found the word 'Shooting' and count the times the program found the word. I wont send the selenium part only the part that I struggle with. If you have any suggestions I would be thankful.

Here's the code:

```
string1 = "Shooting"
index = 0
num = 0
file=open('Information.txt', 'r')

for word in file:
    index +1
    num+1
    if string1 in word:
        print("I Found",string1)
        print(num)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you incriment index if the check returns true

Comment: Might want to edit out Selenium from the tag.

Comment: Without the Information.txt it would be hard to confirm, but, it is possible that you have "Shooting" and "shooting" appear in the txt file. Python is doing a case-sensitive comparison. You should convert string1 and word to lowercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incrementing is done using the `+=` operator, not the `+` operator. I believe this fix should make it work:

```
string1 = "Shooting"
index = 0
num = 0
file=open('Information.txt', 'r')

for word in file:
    index += 1
    num += 1
    if string1 in word:
        print("I Found",string1)
        print(num)
```

EDIT: @TechGeek makes a good point about where you are actually incrementing the variables; num would probably want to be within the if check.

Comment: You really helped me I'm so thankful for that

Answer (score 0):

It should be written as:

```
Index +=1
```